# Wrong SPI signals in logic analyzer

Tags: spi, communication, tms570

We're trying to send some data over SPI. So we've coded a few lines of code for that purpose. But in the picture you can see, sometimes data cannot be retrieved accurately. The original data we want to send is **0x1111** but as you see the SPI CLOCK part, sometimes the computer doesn't see the final "rising edge" situation. As a result of that problem, the data retrieved as **0x1118**.

In theoretically, we could not understand the cause of the problem and therefore could not intervene in the code. **What may cause this problem?**

Code for sending the data:

```c
mibSpiInit();
while(1){
    mibSpiSetData(mibSpiREGx, SpiGroupNo, transmitBuffer);
    mibSpiTransfer(mibSpiREGx, SpiGroupNo);
    while(!(mibSpiIsTransferCompleted(mibSpiREGx,SpiGroupNo); 
}
```

Has been used an a ***TMS570***.

[image: The problem Image]

Comment: I'd be more suspect of the logic analyzer decoding, are you sure that's what the other side is seeing?

Comment: Check the errata? Also check if other messages are garbled in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at the clock decoding, it triggers on both edges so it goes out of sync. The waveform itself looks okay at this zoom level. It may be a bug in the software. Or there is actually a glitch in the waveform so the logic analyzer really sees an extra transition there, do zoom in and take a look. Do note that for about 1 MHz SPI clock, your 500 MHz sampling rate is quite unrealistic.

Comment: Thanks for replying, we connect both of microcontroller and we saw that the data is coming 100% accurately. Probably the software was the problem.

Comment: Most likely cause is not even the software, but too fast sampling rate combined with relatively slow signal edges combined with noise from ground bounce that exceeds the hysteresis threshold between logic states. You can zoom in to see the glitch so you don't need to guess.

Comment: The Logic software has a glitch filter which you can use to remove these. Just click the gear icon on the channel label of the clock channel, and select "Enable Glitch filter".
Before that, zoom in on the edge where you see the clock indicator going the wrong way, and measure the glitch width, so you have an idea what setting to use for the glitch filter. https://support.saleae.com/user-guide/using-logic/software-glitch-filter